# HAML =form.submit add a class with t() stopping it

Tags: javascript, html, haml

I need to add a class of `btn` and `btn-primary` to:

```
= f.submit t('.save',  default: t('helpers.links.save'))
- if question_set.shared?
```

So that it matches the rest of my page. But no matter what I do it does not put those classes in.

I have tried:

```
= f.submit, :class => "form_submit"
```

Placed it everywhere I just cant get it to work. If I place it in front of the `t(` it errors out.

Comment: Fixed english and code blocks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case anyone wants to know how to do something like this it works like this.

```
= f.submit t('.save', default: t('helpers.links.save')), class: 'btn btn-primary'
```